# Comparing/finding out changed files across branches in Subversion

Tags: svn, ankhsvn

I'm currently working off the version of my project from the head from Subversion.  I have a branch which is an older version of the project.  I now need to find out which files have changed and what are their changes.

I was wondering are there any ways to find out?  Are there special tools required to do so, or just regular commands?  I'm interested in finding out the steps and command on how to do it.

I have Subversion integrated into Visual Studiou 2008.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [SVN manual for the `svn diff` command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html). The third usage should probably achieve what you want:

```
svn diff OLD-URL[@OLDREV] NEW-URL[@NEWREV]
```

Comment: @Craig McQueen: I couldn't find the command to run diff in my current SVN.  What about for AnkhSVN?

Comment: The way I described is using the command-line tools. If you want to do it within AnkhSVN... I don't use it myself, and I can't see anything that looks helpful at http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/com.collabnet.doc.anksvn_001/action/ankh_diff.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the merge wizard to figure out what can possibly be merged to the branch if that helps.

- Right click the solution
- Subversion -> Merge
- Choose "Merge a range of revisions"
- Choose "Select revisions on the next page" and choose the other branch (not the one you're currently working on)

The next page that comes up is meant to be used what revisions you want to merge. It lists only the revisions that *can* be merged (that haven't been merged yet). You can look through the revisions, and the changes files in each revision. If you right click or double click on a file, you can take a look at the changes in the file/revision.